# How to work with scroll() JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to do something when window scrolls to a certain position

Fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/to1uuvnb/16/

**HTML:**

```
<div id="container"></div>
<div id="target"></div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#container {
    min-height:300px;
    max-width:400px;
    background-color:#000;
}
#target { 
    min-height:1000px;
    max-width:400px;
    background-color:red;
}
```

**JavaScript:**

```
$('#target').scroll(function() {
    if($(this).scrollTop() > 10) {
        alert('');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You are attaching the scroll event to a div that has no `overflow: auto;` or `overflow: scroll;` set. And the question title does not seem to match with your code, I believe you want to attach the event to `window` instead:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
```

https://jsfiddle.net/to1uuvnb/17/

Comment: can you please update the fiddle code it will be easy for me

Comment: i just want when the scrolls cross the black container then it shows alert how can we do that

Comment: i can't use (window).scroll() in my project cause there are too many div elements in my project and if i use window.scroll() then i have to give it top  spacing from the starting of the page